# JApplet not connecting to internet issue - How to make trusted?

Tags: java, swing, applet, httpurlconnection, japplet

I have an application which I'm using as a JApplet. It accesses the internet, but I've found the issue why it's not working is because it apparently is not trusted.

How can I go about making the application trusted :)

Comment: One way to run the applet sand-boxed is to add a proxy to your server that fetches the content and serves it 'locally' to the applet.  (And before you ask, I have not done it, and your Google is as good as mine.)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make an applet trusted, is to sign all jars.

If you do not have an official certificate, you can create your own which the user then needs to accept.

Use "keytool" in the JDK for these operations.

Comment: How would I actually do this?

Comment: I found this tutorial by searching for `applet keytool` on Google: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html.  It appears to cover the basics.